# How to calculate the angle between two vectors without using the dot product?

Tags: matrices, inner-products, tensor-products, convolution

Recently I needed to perform the convolution between a matrix and several predefined kernels, this can be broken down into point product operations. My problem then is this: given a vector $v$ compute the following products points: $v.u_{1}$, $v.u_{2}$ ...$v.u_{i}$ .... $v.u_{n}$. My idea to program this in an optimal way is the following: supposing that I have precalculated the norms $|u_{1}|$, $|u_{1}|$...$|u_{i}|$ ..... $|u_{n}|$ and that I calculate the norm of V (this is only necessary to do it once in time of execution) then each product point would be reduced to $|v_{1}||u_{1}|cos(alfa_{vu_{i}})$, where $alfa_{vu_{i}}$ is the angle between $v$ and $u_{i}$. However until now I have not found a more optimal way than the same dot product to calculate the angle between 2 vectors, or at least approximate it.

**Extra information**

To perform the convolution between an image $I$ and several kernels $U$, it is required to calculate the dot product between all the sub rectangle of $I$ and all the kernels $U$ (I assume the same size for all the kernels: width $w$ and height $h$). To calculate the norm of each sub-rectangle $|rect_{wh}(V)|$ in time of execution is very simple, for this first one calculates $I*I$ (multiplication of array) and then the [integral image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summed-area_table) $S$ of $I*I$, in this way it can be calculated optimally $|rect_{wh}(V)|$ in each sub-angle in the following way: $\sqrt{S(i,j)+S(i+h,j+w)-(S(i,j+w)+S(i+h,j))}$, where $i$, $j$ are the kernel evaluation coordinates (top left) and $w$ and $h$ are the dimensions of the kernel.

Next I show how the convolution of a single kernel with an image is performed, in each position the operation $Rect_{wh}(I).u_{i}$ is performed.

[image]

Now suppose that this same image $I$ have to convolve with many kernels $u_{1}$, $u_{2}$ ... $u_{i}$ ... $u_{n}$, assuming you have an approximation of the $alfa$ angle, an efficient way that I have thought is to compute $|Rect_{wh}(I)||u_{i}|*cos(alfa)$, the norms of each kernels are pre-computed and the norm of each $Rect$ of $I$ is calculated using the integral image technique described in the following example:

[image]

Comment: Why is it that you would prefer to compute $|v||u_i|\cos(\alpha_{vu_i})$ rather than the dot product. The dot product is already an extremely low cost operation.

Comment: I don't think any clever way of computing an angle between the vectors will win over just multiplying and adding $n$ times in efficiency. Also, I don't know how you are computing norms of the vectors, but I think computing norms is about as efficient as computing dot products. Not to mention that you are computing two norms for each product

Comment: @user160738: The norms may possibly be re-used at least for the kernels $U$ if they stay the same throughout, but still.

Comment: please review my question again, I have added new information that explains the reason why to approximate the angle between 2 vectors. Currently working in convolutional neural networks, the bottleneck of these learning machines is the convolution. If I found a way to approximate the angle between 2 vectors then I could use the integral image technique to approximate the convolution in a very efficient way.

Comment: The norm of each kernel is precomputed, in time of execution it is only required to calculate the norm of the input, in this case the image $I$.

Comment: @RogerFigueroaQuintero: You do realize that computing the norm of the input is the same as computing a square root of it's dot product with itself, right? Hence I do not see how it can be cheaper anyway. Unless I am missing something.

Comment: The computation of the norm of each sub-angle Rect of the image $I$ is done using the integral image and the computation of the norm of the kernels is something that has pre-calculated. Normally I would have to make the product point between each kernel and each $Rect (I)$, however, this product point can be replaced by the multiplication of $|Rect (I)||ui|cos(alpha)|, so my problem really is to find an efficient way to approximate alpha.

Comment: I understand that you want to compute $v^T U$ for a matrix $U$ and a vector $v$. This is an operations which is incompatible with modern computers because it has low arithmetic intensity. You do $O(n^2)$ operations on $O(n^2)$ data. Turn, twist and rewrite as much as you want there is nothing you can do. There is only one thing which can save you. If you need $v_j^T U$ for say $n$ vectors  $v_j$. Then you can do a dense matrix matrix product $V^T U$. This requires $O(n^3)$ operation on $O(n^2)$ data. This operation can run close to the peak performance of your machine.

Comment: Matrix multiplication is an option, there are even matrix multiplication algorithms whose $O <O(n^3)$ (sub-cubic), however I wanted to explore the idea that I describe in my question.